# Careers: <email address temporarily hidden>

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I got my first Interest for my CV on the careers site. The process was a little confusing though. I saw part of a message with part of it edited as "<email address temporarily hidden>". I didn't understand why it was hidden, and the message I was shown wasn't really enough to make a Interested or Not interested decision.

My first instinct was to respond "Hey your email address was blocked by the site, I think there is a different workflow you should be using" but upon clicking "Interested" I was given the full unedited email address.

Can you post some sort of message like "The un-edited full message will be displayed once you are interested in this position." It might also be useful to have a "Find out more" option before becoming Interested in a position.

Comment: I think it's hidden, until you click interested (but not sure, since I said "no thanks")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea -- we'll add a line under the message to indicate this.